# Youtube Readable stream, merge then trim using ffmpeg and ytdl-core

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, ytdl

I am using FFmpeg-static in my express server to merge audio and video coming from Youtube Readable Stream then Trim. seems ok and working but im getting an error

> ffmpeg video input stream error: Error: write EPIPE
>
> ffmpeg audio input stream error: Error: write EPIPE

then the triiming process has a glitch like freeze on the first second of the video output  here is my code

```
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", attachment;  filename="${encodeURIComponent(info.videoDetails.title)}.mp4");

  let ffmpegArgs = [
      '-y', // Overwrite output file without asking
      '-i', 'pipe:3', // Read video stream from pipe 3
      '-i', 'pipe:4',
      '-map', '0:v',
      '-map', '1:a',
      '-c:v', 'copy',
      '-preset', 'ultrafast',
      '-b:v', '5000k',
      '-maxrate', '5000k',
      '-bufsize', '10000k',
      '-c:a', 'libmp3lame',
      '-crf', '18',
      '-preset', 'veryfast',
      '-movflags', 'frag_keyframe+empty_moov',
      '-f', 'mp4',
      '-loglevel', 'error'
  ];

  if (startTime && endTime) {
      ffmpegArgs = ffmpegArgs.concat(['-ss', startTime, '-to', endTime]); // Duration of the trimmed video
  }

  ffmpegArgs.push('-');

  let video = ytdl(url, { filter: 'videoonly', format: selectedFormat , highWaterMark: 1 << 25 })
  let audio = ytdl(url, { filter: 'audioonly', quality: 'highestaudio', highWaterMark: 1 << 25  });
  const ffmpegProcess = cp.spawn(ffmpeg, ffmpegArgs, {
      stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'],
  });

  video.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[3]); // Video stream to stdin (fd 3)
  audio.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[4]);
      // Output the resulting merged and trimmed video to a file
      ffmpegProcess.stdio[1].pipe(res);

      // Handle the close event of the ffmpeg process
      ffmpegProcess.on('close', (code) => {
          if (code !== 0) {
            console.error(`ffmpeg process exited with code ${code}`);
          } else {
            console.log('ffmpeg process completed successfully');
            downloadedVideos.push({
              title: info.videoDetails.title,
              url: url,
              format: format
            });
          }
        });
```

> to the trim process i tried to move the -ss and -to to different lines but the freeze issue is still there
>
> i did try to add and error handling event but the output error is still the same error: write EPIPE

```
  // Pipe the video and audio streams to the ffmpeg process
          video.on('error', (err) => {
            console.error(`video stream error: ${err}`);
           });
            
          audio.on('error', (err) => {
            console.error(`audio stream error: ${err}`);
          });
            
          ffmpegProcess.stdio[3].on('error', (err)=> {
            console.error(`ffmpeg video input stream error: ${err} `);
          });
            
          ffmpegProcess.stdio[4].on('error', (err) => {
            console.error(`ffmpeg audio input stream error: ${err} `);
          });
```